# How to derive this parametrization of a solid cone

Tags: calculus, solid-geometry

From Wikipedia:

> A right circular cone with height $h$ and aperture $2\theta$, whose axis is the $z$-coordinate axis and whose apex is the origin, is described parametrically as
>   $$F(s,t,u) = \left(u \tan s \cos t, u \tan s \sin t, u \right),$$
>   where $s,t,u$ range over $[0,\theta)$, $[0,2\pi)$, and $[0,h]$, respectively.

How is this derived? Can someone walk me through it?

Comment: Let $P$ be a point in the cone and draw a perpendicular from $P$ to the $x-y$ plane. Let $s$ be the angle  at $P$ in triangle $OPQ$   (  $O$ being the origin). Let $t$ be the angle made by $OQ$ with the $x-axis$. Then $P$ becomes $(u\tan s  \cos t, u\tan s  \sin t,u)$.